# Element and image positioning in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a box that sits inside a Bootstrap framework. the box is created with flexbox in order to make it flexible in various screen sizes.

When I add an image I have some issues with the background still being visible behind the image - as if the image doesn't cover the entire box.

It is hard to explain. 
Also, it seems to be only in Chrome. In Firefox, however, the (green) title bar above the image doesn't quite stick to the bottom.
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/150252/).

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="gridbox">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="header">Left box</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/300?image=1" alt="550x300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="gridbox">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="header">Right box</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/300?image=2" alt="550x300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css (vendor prefixes removed):

```
.gridbox {
  height: 133px;
  background-color: #f90;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 2px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 4;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(133, 174, 51, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.box2 {
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gridbox .box2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  filter: brightness(100%) blur(0);
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.gridbox:hover img {
  filter: brightness(90%) blur(0);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You have a fixed height but flexible width. This means that the images can't always conform to the box due to their aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if understand  well but you can try this.

```css
.col{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.gridbox {
  height: 133px;
  background-color: #f90;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 2px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 4;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(133, 174, 51, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.gridbox .box2 {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gridbox .box2 img {
  
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 133px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit:cover;

  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  filter: brightness(100%) blur(0);
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.gridbox:hover img {
  filter: brightness(90%) blur(0);
}

body {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="gridbox">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="header">Left box</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/300?image=1" alt="550x300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="gridbox">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="header">Right box</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/300?image=2" alt="550x300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Using `object-fit` actually seemes to help. But sometimes, in certain window sizes or when when the browser is being resized, the images doesn't seem to cover the whole flex box. Maybe it's a browser rendering flaw.
Anyway, your suggestion made it better. Thanks.